# How to prevent 'conda activate' calls inside a bash script to take arguments from the script?

Tags: bash, arguments, conda

I have a bash script where I pass multiple arguments in flags (previously positional arguments, still had the same problem). Inside the script I activate and deactivate different conda virtual environments to run different programs.

I would like to add an option for the script to stop if anything goes wrong in the middle (it is a long workflow with many steps, some of which are lengthy and/or computationally costly). For this I thought of adding set -e at the beginning of the script.

However this makes the script stops at the first activation step since the conda activate commands try to take all the arguments I pass to the script as theirs too. Example:

```
user@pc$ bash myscript.sh -a file1 -b file2 -c path1 -d string1
activate does not accept more than one argument:
['-a', 'file1', '-b', 'file2', '-c', 'path1', '-d', 'string1']
user@pc$
```

Somewhat unrelated, please note how conda parses the flag and the argument content as space-delimited separate arguments.

Inside the script I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
... [stuff here, defining all the flags] ...
source /home/user/programs/miniconda3/bin/activate
... [the rest of the script]
```

I have browsed around here and in github with little success. I've seen many threads of people having trouble with space-containing arguments and conda, but my problem is not exactly that one. I saw a GitHub issue where they suggested to remove @args of the conda activate script, however 1) this may break things and 2) I have multiple environments and keeping track of such a workaround for every environment is not very optimized.

My first question is: can it be somehow specified that arguments of the parent script are NOT taken by the conda activate steps?

In the end, what I want to do is to be able to stop the script if something goes wrong in the middle. Therefore, my second question is: Is there another way to stop the script if something goes wrong, e.g. for every major program in the script to contemplate whether to continue or not? What would be the best practice?

Please let me know if anything isn't clear, this is my first time posting here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps consider `conda run` instead of environment activation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to clear the positional parameters

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
... [stuff here, defining all the flags] ...

# if you need, store the current positional params
args=("$@")

# clear the params
set --

source /home/user/programs/miniconda3/bin/activate
... [the rest of the script]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Glenn, I specified ```set -- ``` after storing the parameters and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Why source `activate`? In my experience, when sourcing a file you're generally defining common functions, so there should not be any execution of code. If you are expecting to execute code, though, then you need to understand that it will be run as if it were actually typed in at that point in the calling script itself, so if it's going to process the positional parameters, they'd better be in a state to be processed (i.e. see glenn jackman's answer).

Can your code work by just calling `activate` instead of sourcing it, passing in only the parameters that are meant for it?

---

Added:

I oversimplified a bit when I said "it will be run as if it were actually typed in at that point"; my apologies for the confusion, I should have been more precise. It executes the sourced file (the `activate` script in your case) in the context of the current shell environment, as opposed to executing it in a sub-shell. The `activate` script is being executed, though, make no mistake about that.

From the man page:

> Read and execute commands from filename in the current shell
> environment and return the exit status of the last command executed
> from filename. [...] If any arguments are supplied, they become the
> positional parameters when filename is executed. Otherwise the
> positional parameters are unchanged.

I didn't know that last part, and that may be the key to what you need to do. Be careful if and how you manipulate the positional parameters inside of the sourced script, as it could affect the calling script:

```
</tmp/so2603> $ cat foo
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -n "FOO #1:"; for i; do echo -n " <$i>"; done; echo
. bar "$3"
echo -n "FOO #2:"; for i; do echo -n " <$i>"; done; echo

</tmp/so2603> $ cat bar
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -n "  BAR #1:"; for i; do echo -n " <$i>"; done; echo
shift
echo -n "  BAR #2 (after shift):"; for i; do echo -n " <$i>"; done; echo

if [[ -n "$BAZ" ]]; then
    set -- "baz"
    echo -n "  BAR #3 (after set):"; for i; do echo -n " <$i>"; done; echo
fi
```

running them first without setting `BAZ`, and then with:

```
</tmp/so2603> $ ./foo one two "three four" five
FOO #1: <one> <two> <three four> <five>
  BAR #1: <three four>
  BAR #2 (after shift):
FOO #2: <one> <two> <three four> <five>

</tmp/so2603> $ BAZ=true ./foo one two "three four" five
FOO #1: <one> <two> <three four> <five>
  BAR #1: <three four>
  BAR #2 (after shift):
  BAR #3 (after set): <baz>
FOO #2: <baz>
```

The positional parameters inside of a function, though, are in a different/separate scope from the "global" positional parameters, so you can source from a function and avoid them altogether:

```
</tmp/so2603> $ cat foo
#!/usr/bin/env bash

call_bar()
{
    . bar
}

echo -n "FOO #1:"; for i; do echo -n " <$i>"; done; echo
call_bar
echo -n "FOO #2:"; for i; do echo -n " <$i>"; done; echo
```

The `bar` script remains unchanged, giving you:

```
</tmp/so2603> $ ./foo one two "three four" five
FOO #1: <one> <two> <three four> <five>
  BAR #1:
  BAR #2 (after shift):
FOO #2: <one> <two> <three four> <five>

</tmp/so2603> $ BAZ=true ./foo one two "three four" five
FOO #1: <one> <two> <three four> <five>
  BAR #1:
  BAR #2 (after shift):
  BAR #3 (after set): <baz>
FOO #2: <one> <two> <three four> <five>
```

---

FYI, there are lots of pros and cons to using `set -e`:

[BashFaq - Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

[David Pashley's Writing Robust Bash Shell Scripts](https://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts/#id2596016)

I generally prefer to use it when I need strict error checking, but each script and programmer is unique and should be evaluated independently.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In short answer: the code doesn't work by just calling ```activate ``` . I've tried to run it by just calling ```activate```, but it does not behave as desired. I need it to activate the conda virtual environment and that command in itself does not need any user-provided parameters. However it seems to work if I clear the positional parameters after storing them, as suggested by Glenn Jackman.

Comment: Also, thanks a lot for those links! I would like to better understand what you meant in "If you are expecting to execute code, though, then you need to understand that it will be run as if it were actually typed in at that point in the calling script itself". I am expecting to execute code in my script, using the arguments I passed, yes, but I am not expecting to execute it in the ```source ... activate``` step. Also, do you mean as if the positional arguments were typed in at that point in the script? Apologies, I am not well versed in this.